# Chrome dev tools honors media queries, but browser doesn't

Tags: google-chrome, responsive-design, developer-tools

I have media queries in a css file set from 0-500px and 501-1250px and so on...

My CSS breakpoints work great in the screen emulator in the Chrome developer tools when I have "Emulate Mobile" checked in the "emulation" tab.  When that is unchecked or when I view it in the browser without dev tools open, it doesn't honor the breakpoints.

The breakpoints also work fine in Firefox's "Responsive Design Mode" but not in the regular browser when I close the dev tools.

I'm not sure how to best ask the question--Is it possible to get the styles to work in a regular browser?

here is a video of my screen demonstrating the problem:

https://youtu.be/_FBoDek0Ou0

Comment: How are you writing them? Are you checking for screen etc, or just writing `@media all and (max-width: 500px;)`

Comment: /@media only screen and (min-device-width: 501px) and (max-device-width: 1250px)  {
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 500px) {

Comment: /@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1251px) and (max-device-width: 2600px)  {
    /@media only screen and (min-device-width: 501px) and (max-device-width: 1250px)  {
    /@media only screen and (max-device-width: 500px) {

Comment: I'm new to this and I kept getting yelled at by the formatting tips for using too many "at" symbols, so I had to stick slashes in there, and it wouldn't let me hit return for a new line.

Comment: What program are you using to write these?

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text.

Comment: Could you add some of the code to your main question so I can see how you've written it fully?

Comment: /* DESKTOPS*/
\@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1251px) and (max-device-width: 2600px)  {


 Is there anything in particular you think might be helpful?    /* TABLETS  */
 \@media only screen and (min-device-width: 501px) and (max-device-width: 1250px)  {

Comment: I simply can't seem to get the hang of how I'm supposed to reply using the "2 space" "4 space" thing and why it hates @ symbols

Comment: is it possible to post a private youtube link to a screen capture of my problem?

Comment: Here is a video of my screen showing the behavior of the browser and screen dev tools.[link]https://youtu.be/_FBoDek0Ou0  It has no audio but the text should be clear.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at your video, the media queries look like the issue. You are checking for device width, which the browser sees as the FULL SIZE of your screen, rather than the width of the browser.

Try writing them like this:

```
@media all and (min-width: 1251px) and (max-width: 2600px) {
    */ code here /*
}
```

Notice it is checking just for the `min-width` rather than `min-device-width`.

I suggest you also have a read of these: https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/ and http://bradfrost.com/blog/post/7-habits-of-highly-effective-media-queries/ to get more of a grasp on how they work.

Comment: I found must use min-device-width in Chrome devtools, otherwise it won't work. Version 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @spikeyang are you setting your viewport correctly with the meta tag? Can you share some code? No need to downvote a correct answer because it doesn't apply to your unique situation...